# App Tracking Transparency & GDPR for AdMob in Unity Mobile Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, gdprconsentform

[AdMob Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB6XL.png)

I have a mobile game where I use AdMob ads. Recently, AdMob announced that I have to publish my GDPR consent message by 16 January 2024. However, I have a few questions about that:

- At least on iOS, the game automatically asks for an App Tracking Transparency consent. Since iOS already asks for the tracking permission, do I still need to show the GDPR message from AdMob?
- Let's say I'm showing ads from different providers using mediation. Do I have to show each of their GDPR messages separately before loading the ad?
- Can I just set the npa flag to 1 and not show the GDPR message? (`npa=1`)
- I don't want to annoy the users too much with all of these consent pop-ups. So, what would be the best approach here?

I researched on the internet but couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, read the ["Get Started](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/privacy) for more details, please.
2. No, show AdMobs UMP and be sure that you have already configured your AdMob account [Privacy Messaging](https://apps.admob.com/v2/privacymessaging)
3. if you are using the UMP you do not need to set npa=1. https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/I6j0Pr-_ziY/m/VOH06zsWAQAJ
4. The UMP will be shown only once even if you show it forced. Show the UMP is not required at all, but if you need to show personalized ads and earn more revenue you need to show that. The UMP will be shown not for all users depending on their country.